# Programatically set OnSelectedIndexChanged for a ddl

Tags: c#, asp.net

a minor question but it's driving me nuts.  I'm programatically generating about 50 DDLs based on a database schema (i.e. item 1 can do a,b,c item 2 can do d, e, a, etc etc).

If I was just writing the markup, I could specify:

asp:DropDownList 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="funTimes"

and be done with it, unfortunately, I'm just not sure how to set that programatically.  I found a "SelectedIndexChanged" event, but I'm not sure what I need to return in terms of an event handler when all I want to do is set the method called.  I realize I could write 50 methods:

ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged()
ddl2_SelectedIndexChanged()
etc etc

but that solution isn't terribly flexible, especially when I really only want the same method called.  Is there a good way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?  Any input is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set it from your code behind

```
DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler ( funTimes );
```

You can set this from the Page_Load EventHandler or even from within the funTimes EventHandler.

Comment: You rock my socks.  Sorry I wasn't seeing the obvious tonight, I really really appreciate the reply.

Comment: please click the checkbox if this was helpful. (I don't think you can upvote with your rep)

Comment: Yup, sorry it actually makes me wait a few minutes before I click the accept ;)